# Reading value from list using jQuery each statement

Tags: jquery, html, each

I have this statement

```
<div class="divShow">
   <ul id="ulShow">           
     <li>
       <h3 class="CompanyShow">A</h3>
       <h2 class="ShowTitle">S</h2>                
       <input class="ExpShow" type="button" value="Edit">           
     </li>
     <li>
       <h3 class="CompanyShow">A2</h3>
       <h2 class="ShowTitle">T1</h2>
       <input class="ExpShow" type="button" value="Edit">
      <li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click `"Edit"` button I have to display the corresponding data.

When I click the `"Edit"` button of the first list then it should display `A`, and if I click the second `li` it should dislay `A2`.

How can I do this using jQuery?

```
 $('.EditExp').live('click',function(){
     $('.divShow ul li').each(function(){
         alert($(this).parent().find('h3.CompanyShow').html());                 
     });                 
 });
```

Comment: FYI use `on` instead of `live` to be current with latest jQuery versions and future support

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.  The idea here is that I am putting a click handler on all the buttons and then i am choosing the `.CompanyShow` element that is relative to the button only.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/yYu2K/9/)**

```
$('.ExpShow').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    alert(  $this.prevAll('.CompanyShow').text());     
}); // end on click
```

Comment: Or `$this.siblings('.CompanyShow').text();     `

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ExpShow').click( function() {
  var html = $(this).closest('li').find('.CompanyShow').html();
  alert( html );
});
```

Comment: going by his sample code so far op is trying to find the value not show/hide the DOM elements

Comment: yes you are right. i just misunderstood by seeing " ... it should display `A` .. ".  i updated the answer :)